# How can I call a class method on its instance?

Tags: ruby, oop

`a1` is a method on `A`.

```
module A
  def self.a1
    puts "I am defined in A"
  end
end

class Sample
  include A
end

samp = Sample.new
```

How can I call `samp.a1`?

```
puts samp.a1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to keep in mind here:

- If you declare module methods with the `self` prefix that means they're able to be directly called on the module, like `A.a1`, but it also means they *won't* be imported with `include`. Those declared without self are "mix-in methods", or those that will automatically be imported on `include`.
- If you `include` more than one module which defines a method then the last module included will be the one that actually gets called.

The fix here is either to change `def self.a1` to `def a1` in `module A` or instead call it directly with `A.a1`. If B also defines `a1` then it will have precedence *unless* you `include B` first, making it lower priority.

Comment: A lot of tutorials make Ruby mixins extremely complicated, and I really don't understand why. `include` makes the mixin the superclass. And that's it. There's literally nothing more to understand about Ruby mixins. It's just standard boring old inheritance.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The confusing thing about them is if you've never used a language that allows this kind of selective composition. Most people are used to single or multiple inheritance, and those are usually locked in at the time of definition. With `include` you can add additional "superclass" type inheritance arbitrarily at any time. That seems very odd at first, like how you can also do that on individual objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you know this sort of thing will happen ahead of time, you can use alias as you're including modules (note this changes the method definitions from `def self.a1` to `def a1` so that they are properly included as instance methods):

```
module A
  def a1
    puts "I am defined in A"
  end
end

module B
  def a1
    puts "I am defined in B"
  end
end

class Sample
  include A
  alias :a_a1 :a1
  include B
  alias :b_a1 :a1
end

samp = Sample.new
samp.a_a1
samp.b_a1
samp.a1
```

running this outputs:

```
I am defined in A
I am defined in B
I am defined in B
```

As a general rule, though, I would avoid this situation and rename one of the methods in the modules, if you're able to; though sometimes you're not able to for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for a1, then this should work:

```
class Sample
  include A
  def a1
    self.class.a1
  end
end
```

If you need it for all methods, you can try Catching the NoMethodError with a send-command for the class, but that is usually overkill.

Comment: This won't work with `include` - you would need to `extend` instead.